# Python 3 Шифрование заголовка и пароля через sha512

Tags: python-3.x, api, криптография, шифрование, тестирование

Пытаюсь написать автотест на Python 3 для тестирования одного API. В теле запроса должно идти следующее:

```
{
    "first_param": 19,
    "random_param": "0.023912391286381238",
    "sign": "сlient_passwd",
    "sysId": 1
}
```

Cначала делается sha512 для `client_passwd`. Далее по документации:

> Вычисляем функцию HMAC-SHA512 от полного JSON, в качестве  ключа используется SHA512 от пароля.

И вот тут у меня возникли трудности. Далее вся эта зашифрованная JSON-нина по новой передается в `sign` Черновой вариант кода:

```
import json
import requests

import random
import hashlib
import hmac


user_password = "qwerty121" #пароль
user_password = bytes(user_password.encode('utf-8'))  #пароль в байтовую строку
hash_password = hashlib.sha512(user_password)  #sha512 на пароль

user_password = hash_password.hexdigest() #шестнадцатиричное представление

#print(user_password)
url_t = "https://hostURL"
r_number = random.random()
s_number = random.randint(100000,200000)
#print(s_number)
r_string = str(r_number) + str(s_number) + " :)" #генерация рандома
#print(r_string)
payload = {"first_param": 11,  "sysId" : 1,  "random_param": r_string, "sign":user_password} #json-тела запроса
byte_payload = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')#json тела запроса в байтовый формат
hash_byte_payload = hashlib.sha512(byte_payload) #sha512 на json-тело
hash_byte_payload = hash_byte_payload.hexdigest() #шестнадцатиричный вид для всего json - тела


response = requests.post(url_t, json={"first_param": 11,  "sysId":1,  "random_param": r_string, "sign": hash_byte_payload})
```

Я понимаю, что скорее всего ошибку допустила в "`Вычисляем функцию HMAC-SHA512 от полного JSON, в качестве ключа используется SHA512 от пароля`", но не имею никакого понятия, как c помощью SHA512 от пароля зашифровать весь JSON.

Comment: Вопрос не сложный, но есть неясные моменты. 1) "`шестнадцатиричное представление`" – а это точно нужно? 2) А точно ли подпись должна класться в тот же JSON, который она подписывает? Это немного нелогично `(:`

Comment: 1) шестнадцаричное представление - это уже я сделала, по идее же без этого хэш512 байтовым будет. 2) да, так по документации. Как это на алгоритме выглядит : вычисляется хэш512 от пароля пользователя, через него вычисляется хэш для json,  который я привела в примере. А далее этим хэшем-для -json json же подписывается, значение sign в нем изменяется на хэш-для -json и отправляется запрос на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код и комменты постарался сохранить как есть, но внёс правки

```py
import json
import requests

import random
import hashlib
import hmac


# пароль
user_password = "qwerty121"
# пароль в байтовую строку
user_password = user_password.encode('utf-8')
# sha512 на пароль с переводом в байты
hash_password = hashlib.sha512(user_password).digest()


# генерация рандома
r_string = str(random.random()) + str(random.randint(100000,200000)) + " :)"
# json-тело запроса
payload = {"first_param": 11,  "sysId" : 1,  "random_param": r_string}
# json тела запроса в байты
byte_payload = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')


# Рассчитываем подпись, переводим в HEX
sign = hmac.new(hash_password, byte_payload, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
# Добавляяем подпись в JSON
payload["sign"] = sign
# На всякий случай: имейте в виду, что byte_payload хранит
# старое значение, не соответствующее обновлённому payload


url_t = "https://hostURL"
response = requests.post(url_t, json=payload)
```

Однако постановка задачи всё равно выглядит нелепо: подписи делаются для того, чтобы проверять целостность приходящих данных. А так получается, что подпись рассчитывается по одному JSON, а отправляется уже другой, и подпись не проверить, что делает бессмысленной всю процедуру. Либо вы неправильно поняли ТЗ, либо оно очень не очень... В норме подпись отправляется параллельно подписанным данным, которые не меняются и соответствуют этой подписи.

Есть и другие неясные моменты, но этот главный.

Comment: ТЗ видимо действительно не очень, коллегия разработчиков донесла до меня такой смысл - сначала расчитывается подпись для реального пароля пользователя. Затем через нее расчитывается подпись для  json из примера, и рассчитывается правильно только если sign = "client_passwd". Далее новая подпись вставляется в поле  sign   и это json отправляется в запросе на сервер.

Comment: Попробовала ваш пример, подпись расчитывает, но сервер ее отбрасывает =(( видимо внутренние проблемы.

Comment: Немного мучений, и все заработало) Я где-то нашла такой вариант преобразования 
 json и он все портил. byte_payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf8')